# Gauge D3, display values positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gauge

I'm trying to use some ready written javascript to make gauge. I'm almost there, but i cannot figure how to manage value captions.

Here is how my code works now: [image]

And this is how I like it to work: [image]

Don't know how to approach to problem. Working with those Math.Pi, Math.cos and Math.sin is just too much for me.

```js
var name = "Value";

var value = 17;


var gaugeMaxValue = 100; 

// data to calculate 
var percentValue = value / gaugeMaxValue; 

////////////////////////

var needleClient;



(function(){

var barWidth, chart, chartInset, degToRad, repaintGauge,
    height, margin, numSections, padRad, percToDeg, percToRad, 
    percent, radius, sectionIndx, svg, totalPercent, width;



  percent = percentValue;

  numSections = 1;
  sectionPerc = 1 / numSections / 2;
  padRad = 0.025;
  chartInset = 10;

  // Orientation of gauge:
  totalPercent = .75;

  el = d3.select('.chart-gauge');

  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  };

  width = el[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  height = width;
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  barWidth = 40 * width / 300;



  //Utility methods 

  percToDeg = function(perc) {
    return perc * 360;
  };

  percToRad = function(perc) {
    return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
  };

  degToRad = function(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
  };

  // Create SVG element
  svg = el.append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  // Add layer for the panel
  chart = svg.append('g').attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")");


  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-first");
  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-second");
  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-third");
  formatValue = d3.format('1%');
  

  


  arc3 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
  arc2 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
  arc1 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)

  repaintGauge = function () 
  {
    perc = 45/100;
    var next_start = totalPercent;
    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 2);
    next_start += perc / 2;


    arc1.startAngle(arcStartRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

    perc = 1-perc;
    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 2);
    next_start += perc / 2;

    arc2.startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

    chart.select(".chart-first").attr('d', arc1);
    chart.select(".chart-second").attr('d', arc2);
 


  }
/////////

    var dataset = [{metric:name, value: value}]

    var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter();

    texts.append("text")
         .text(function(){
              return dataset[0].metric;
         })
         .attr('id', "Name")
         .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 6) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 1.5) + ")")
         .attr("font-size",25)
         .style("fill", "#000000");


    texts.append("text")
         .text(function(){
            return dataset[0].value;
         })
         .attr('id', "Value")
         .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 1.4) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 1.5) + ")")
         .attr("font-size",25)
         .style("fill", "#000000");




    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale0')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 100 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");

    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return gaugeMaxValue/2;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale10')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2.15 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 30) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");


    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return gaugeMaxValue;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale20')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 1.03 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");

  var Needle = (function() {

    //Helper function that returns the `d` value for moving the needle
    var recalcPointerPos = function(perc) {
      var centerX, centerY, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY, thetaRad, topX, topY;
      thetaRad = percToRad(perc / 2);
      centerX = 0;
      centerY = 0;
      topX = centerX - this.len * Math.cos(thetaRad);
      topY = centerY - this.len * Math.sin(thetaRad);
      leftX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      leftY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      rightX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      rightY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      return "M " + leftX + " " + leftY + " L " + topX + " " + topY + " L " + rightX + " " + rightY;
    };

    function Needle(el) {
      this.el = el;
      this.len = width / 2.5;
      this.radius = this.len / 8;
    }

    Needle.prototype.render = function() {
      this.el.append('circle').attr('class', 'needle-center').attr('cx', 0).attr('cy', 0).attr('r', this.radius);

      return this.el.append('path').attr('class', 'needle').attr('id', 'client-needle').attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(this, 0));


    };

    Needle.prototype.moveTo = function(perc) {
      var self,
          oldValue = this.perc || 0;

      this.perc = perc;
      self = this;

      // Reset pointer position
      this.el.transition().delay(100).ease('quad').duration(200).select('.needle').tween('reset-progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress = (1 - percentOfPercent) * oldValue;

          repaintGauge(progress);
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
        };
      });

      this.el.transition().delay(300).ease('bounce').duration(1500).select('.needle').tween('progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress = percentOfPercent * perc;

          repaintGauge(progress);
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
        };
      });

    };


    return Needle;

  })();



  needle = new Needle(chart);
  needle.render();
  needle.moveTo(percent);   

})();
```

```css
       <style type="text/css" src="gauge.css">
            .chart-gauge
            {
              width: 400px;
              margin: 100px auto  
             } 
            .chart-first
            {
                fill: #66AB8C;
            }
            .chart-second
            {
                fill: #ff533d;
            }
  

            .needle, .needle-center
            {
                fill: #000000;
            }
            .text {
                color: "#112864";
                font-size: 16px;
            }


            svg {
              font: 10px sans-serif;
            }


        </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-gauge"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all about changing the translate for `text`

For example (for setting the max value of gauge):

```
  texts.append("text")
    .text(function() {
      return gaugeMaxValue + "%";//i added the percent(%)
    })
    .attr('id', 'scale20')
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 1.08) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")//then change the x and y for the translate
    .attr("font-size", 15)
    .style("fill", "#000000");
```

Similarly for all other text values.

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LJlKKX1xnVwl2LoFBFoO)

Comment: Thanks. That helped my quite much. But I still have one problem. In my final solution this limit 45% is dynamic value. So the label must move depending what value that limit have. That's the math which is just too much for my brains.

Comment: I accept this to Answer, becouse it's actually answers my question that i asked. Even that I also have that positionin problem. Thanks.